# How to make pictures not load blurrey at first

Tags: firefox, internet, image-processing

I noticed on many platforms (including Windows and Android) Firefox loads images blurry at first (especially when viewing google images). How can this be changed? I'd prefer nothing to be loaded at all and that a clear image all at once, or the image to be loaded from the top down or something like that.

Comment: Does it happen if you disable hardware acceleration?

Comment: Spotted your question while revising an answer to a related one.  I don't know if there's an option to suppress progressive rendering, but you might find this link interesting: http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/progressive-jpegs-a-new-best-practice/.